# Value logs in component.ts but cannot display on the template

Tags: angular, typescript

The data has been successfully gotten and it console logs to the component.ts but will not display on the template. I want to get the data to a table, but for now i am trying to display them on a

TAG

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CosterService } from 'projects/tradefigure-lib/src/lib/pages/blinkcoster/coster.service';

import { FormBuilder,FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { commodity, ICommodity } from 'projects/tradefigure-lib/src/lib/pages/blinkcoster/ICommodities.schema';

import { CrudtableService } from '../crudtable.service';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
   CommonModule,
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  selector: 'app-commodity',
  templateUrl: '

',
  styleUrls: ['./commodity.component.css']
})
export class CommodityComponent implements OnInit {
  // commodity: commodity = new commodity(); 
  commodity$!: ICommodity[];

  commoditys = this.commodity$
 
  isEditing: boolean = false
  title = 'crud';
  commodity: ICommodity [] = []
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private CosterService: CosterService,
    private crud: CrudtableService,
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form;
  this.crud.getAll().subscribe({
    next: (res) => {
      this.commodity 
      console.log(res)
    }
  })
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let commodity of commodity$ ">
  <p>{{commodity.offtalkerpriceOID}}</p>
  <p>{{commodity.commodityDescription}}</p>
  <p>{{commodity.unitPrice}}</p>
  <p>{{commodity.unitOfMeasure}}</p>  
</div>
```

I have tried passing the data as observable and using the async pipe on the template and it still doesn't work.

The data displays as alert and is also consoled. but once i use the *ngFor and to display on the template the template turns white.

Any solution to this please?

Comment: Can you also include the template code?

Comment: okay i will do that right away

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Without seeing more code, the issue seems to be in the `ngOnInit` code.</strike>

You are not assigning the value of the response to the actual variable. Hence why it prints in the console (`console.log(res)`) but does not update in the html (you had `this.commodity` with no assignment.).

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.crud.getAll().subscribe(res => {
    this.commodity = res
    console.log(res);
  })
}
```

----------

There are two ways to solve the issue. Depending on if you want to use the  `async` pipe or not.

In either case, the issue is always por assignments in the `ngOnInit` method.

1. With the `async` pipe:

TS code:

```js
export class CommodityComponent implements OnInit {
  commodities$: Observable<ICommodity[]>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.commodities$ = this.crud.getAll();
  }
}
```

We assign the observable returned by `this.crud.getAll()` to the variable `commodities$`. This pattern is from the

HTML code:

```html
<div *ngFor="let commodity of (commodity$ | async)">
  <p>{{commodity.offtalkerpriceOID}}</p>
  <p>{{commodity.commodityDescription}}</p>
  <p>{{commodity.unitPrice}}</p>
  <p>{{commodity.unitOfMeasure}}</p>  
</div>
```

We add the `async` pipe to handle the subscription for us.

2. Without the `async` pipe.

TS code:

```js
export class CommodityComponent implements OnInit {
  commodities: ICommodity[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.crud.getAll().subscribe(res => {
      this.commodities = res;
    })
  }
}
```

Note that we don't need to manage the subscription since all HTTP request auto complete when the request is finished.

HTML code:

```html
<div *ngFor="let commodity of commodities">
  <p>{{commodity.offtalkerpriceOID}}</p>
  <p>{{commodity.commodityDescription}}</p>
  <p>{{commodity.unitPrice}}</p>
  <p>{{commodity.unitOfMeasure}}</p>  
</div>
```